# Live Server ENOENT: no such file or directory, open Error

Tags: node.js, browser, liveserver, enoent

My Live Server extension stopped working after reinstalling node js. In the runtime status tab of the extension, it says ENOENT: no such file or directory, open. It does not open browser, go live button doesn't work as well. I tried adding Windows/system32 to Path in environment viarables, it used to work before, but not this time. What could be the issue? My npm commands work fine, typescript also works.

Tried reinstalling live server - didn't work. Tried updating it- didn't work. Tried reinstalling node, no result. Tried clearing the npm cache - no result. Tried setting env variable path to windows/system32, also no result.

Comment: I have fixed it by changing Live Server setting Proxy> Enable to false.